# getBlob().isGoogleType() returning false for Google Docs file

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api

I need to determine whether files are Google types or not in my script, and I can't seem to figure out why this isn't working. Here's the code snippet:

```js
function transferFiles() {
  var files = DriveApp.getFiles();
  while (files.hasNext()) {
    var file = files.next();
    if (file.getBlob().isGoogleType()) {
      do stuff
    }
  }
}
```

The if statement is returning false for all of my Google files (Docs, Sheets, etc). When I ask it to return `file.getBlob().getContentType()`, it seems like everything is converted to application/pdf.

Am I doing something wrong in this code, or is there another way to determine if a file is a Google type or not?

Comment: Yes, since application/pdf isn't a google type, then that is correct. File.getBlob() will return pdfs. You have the option of specifying different MIME types but none are going to return true to "isGoogleType()"

Comment: But then what is the `isGoogleType()` method for in the first place ? If `getBlob()` always returns `application/pdf`

Answer (score 1):

Some workaround suggestion:

```
function transferFiles() {
  var files = DriveApp.getFiles();
  var googleMimeTypes = [MimeType.GOOGLE_APPS_SCRIPT, 
                         MimeType.GOOGLE_DOCS,
                         MimeType.GOOGLE_DRAWINGS,
                         MimeType.GOOGLE_FORMS,
                         MimeType.GOOGLE_SHEETS,
                         MimeType.GOOGLE_SLIDES];
  while (files.hasNext()) {
    var file = files.next();
    if(googleMimeTypes.indexOf(file.getMimeType()) != -1){
      Logger.log(file.getName() + " is Google Type!");
    } else{
      Logger.log(file.getName() + " is not Google Type!");
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's another suggestion. All Google native formats occupy 0 bytes in your Drive. You can compare the file size inside the loop to figure out if a file is native Google type or not.

```
function transferFiles() {
  var files = DriveApp.getFiles();
  while (files.hasNext()) {
    var file = files.next();
    if (file.getSize() == 0) {
      // do something
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Issue and workaround:

When the blob is retrieved from Google Docs files, the mimeType becomes `application/pdf`. In this case, `isGoogleType()` cannot be used. I thought that this might be a bug. And, it seems that this has been reported at Google issue tracker. [Ref](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/129270277) I thought that in this situation, when `isGoogleType()` is used, this might be required to be the method of Class File.

In order to retrieve only Google Docs files using Google Apps Script, as a workaround, how about using the method of `searchFiles` using the search query of `mimeType contains 'application/vnd.google-apps'`? When this is reflected in the sample script, it becomes as follows.

#### Sample script:

```js
var files = DriveApp.searchFiles("mimeType contains 'application/vnd.google-apps'");
while (files.hasNext()) {
  var file = files.next(); // In this case, the retrieved files are the Google Docs files with the mimeType including the value of "application/vnd.google-apps".

  // do something

}
```

- In this sample script, the files which are the Google Docs files with the mimeType including the value of `application/vnd.google-apps` are retrieved. [Ref](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/mime-types)

#### References:

- [searchFiles(params)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app#searchfilesparams)
- [Search query terms and operators](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/ref-search-terms)